# Cubejs Type declaration in measures for round up decimal values

Tags: javascript, cube, cube.js

is there any method to roundup the decimal values for example in measures i am defining  BaseAmount:{
      sql:'BaseAmount',
      type:`sum`
    },
    I am getting sum of all baseAmount value like this  693.3399999999993 because here I mentioned type as sum I need to round up these values as 693.3 for that what type I need to declare

Comment: To perform this directly in Cube and not in js, you can do:
`BaseAmount:{ sql:'round(sum('BaseAmount'), 1), type:number }`

Comment: This did not work for the cubestore. https://github.com/cube-js/cube/issues/6179

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) function in js. See the below snippet.

```js
let sum = 693.3399999999993;
let rounded = Math.round( sum * 10 ) / 10;

console.log(rounded)
```

Comment: In Need to format the value in cube js  https://cube.dev/docs/measures